# How to update only matching string value of a field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here is my collection:

```
[
  {
    "title": "This is a title",
    "Post": "this is a post"
  },
  {
    "title": "This is a title 2",
    "Post": "this is a post"
  },
  {
    "title": "This is a title",
    "Post": "this is a post"
  },
  {
    "title": "This is a title 2",
    "Post": "this is a post"
  }
]
```

How can I update it's "title" field only if the string value match with "This is a title 2" and change it to "This is a title 3" using MongoDB aggregation? Like this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "This is a title",
    "Post": "this is a post"
  },
  {
    "title": "This is a title 3",
    "Post": "this is a post"
  },
  {
    "title": "This is a title",
    "Post": "this is a post"
  },
  {
    "title": "This is a title 3",
    "Post": "this is a post"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your update query can be simply achieved as below without an aggregation pipeline.

By filtering the documents with `"title": "This is a title 2"` and set the new value to `title` field.

```
db.collection.update({
  "title": "This is a title 2"
},
{
  $set: {
    "title": "This is a title 3"
  }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iOJmoizIOH2)